# Java sorting arraylist using comparator starting from the second object

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

So supposing I have an arraylist named arr and it contains integers

```
arr[0] = 7  
arr[1] = 4  
arr[2] = 1  
arr[3] = 3
```

I want to sort them but excluding the first array which is arr[0] so I want the array to be like this

```
arr[0] = 7  
arr[1] = 1  
arr[2] = 3  
arr[3] = 4
```

Any ideas how to do it? Could this be done by using a comparator?

Comment: pass the array element with second element

Comment: you may have a look here: [Sort an integer array, keeping first in place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44440357/sort-an-integer-array-keeping-first-in-place)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are starting with an array, you can use [`Arrays.asList(T...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-) to construct a `List` view of your array, backed by the real array.

You can use [`List#subList(fromIndex, toIndex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-) to create a view of the list starting from the second item.

If you sort this sublist, your original list (as well as your original array, if you used `asList`, above) will be sorted starting at the second item.

So assuming `arr` is an `ArrayList<Integer>`, all you need is:

```
arr.subList(1, arr.size()).sort(your_comparator);
```